# Force close App after installing on device?

Tags: android, forceclose, android-anr-dialog

My App Installs successfully on device and emulator.In emulator it starts immediately but on **some** devices when user clicks on `open` button in activity that appears after installing App,"ANR" dialog appears and on other devices when user clicks `open` main Activity opens normally.Finally in all devices when user installs App and clicks on it's icon in `Launcher`,main Activity appears normally.Do I forget some things cause this different?

Comment: logcat or it didn't happen :-) But no it should be the same whether you are opening your app from the home screen or the Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem:
My main Activity gets category from intent that requests starting it and use it to decide with IF ELSE block.When user clicks on App's icon in launcher,intent's category is not null(it is `launcher`)but after installing App user clicks `open` button,this intent's category will be `null`,so it causes crash.